# Editing rows based on the user selection

Tags: jquery

with the below code am able to edit row.but when i try to edit another row the first clicked row is still in editable state.how to disable that?

```
  $("#tableid").on("click", "tr", function () {
      $(this).find('td').each(function () {
          var matter = $(this).text();
          if (matter != "") {
              $(this).parents('tr').css('background-color', 'red');
              $(this).addClass("editclass");
              $(this).html("<input type='text' value='" + matter + "'/>");
              $(this).children().first().focus();

              $(this).children().first().keypress(function (e) {
                  if (e.which == 13) {
                      $(this).parents("tr").css("background-color", "white");
                      var newvalue = $(this).val();
                      $(this).parent().text(newvalue);
                      $(this).removeClass("editclass");
                  }
              });
          }
      });
      $(this).children().first().blur(function () {
          $(this).parent().text(matter);
          $(this).removeClass("editclass");
      });
      return false;
  });
```

Comment: A JSFiddle would help others help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When click on tr just perform remove class in tr

Like this

```
 $("#tableid td").each(function () {
     if ($(this).hasClass("editclass")) {
         $(this).parents("tr").css("background-color", "white");
         $(this).html($(this).find("input").val());
         $(this).removeClass("editclass");
     }
 })
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/9z2m8h6g/5/)

Comment: From what I can tell, `tr` is never given the `editclass`

Comment: in this line `$(this).removeClass("editclass");` it'll be

Comment: that line is removing the class from `td`s

Comment: i think your answer will work if you change your selector to `#tableid > tr > td`

Comment: @smerny i was debugging :P forget to remove

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi how to save that edited text using save button

Comment: Where do you wanna save ?

Comment: in the same td cell..if i edit and click save button it should be saved..and if i try to edit the td and move to another that should not save data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94307/discussion-between-anik-islam-abhi-and-tom-boy).